# What do you do when you get stuck in an Eastern Crows loop?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

What do you do when you get caught in an Eastern Crows loop? There are three Eastern Crows cards that get shuffled back into the encounter deck every time they're defeated (supposing none are drawn as shadow effect cards). If you go all the way through the encounter deck you will be left with these cards, and then you're stuck in and endless Eastern Crows loop because you never technically empty the encounter deck so you can't reshuffle the discard pile. If you're playing with Thalin it's even worse, because if he's committed to the quest, then he deals one damage to every enemy as it's dealt. So... Eastern crows comes out > gets dealt one damage > goes back in the deck. But it also has the surge keyword:

[image]

So one more card is drawn from the deck, and it's Eastern Crows again... and the cycle starts over again...

[image][image]

**THALIN**
**Dwarf. Warrior.** 
While Thalin is committed to a quest, deal 1 damage to each enemy as it is revealed by the encounter deck.

**EASTERN CROWS**
**Creature.**
 
Surge.
**Forced:** After Eastern Crows is defeated, *shuffle it back into the encounter deck.*

What's the solution here? Do you just play with Eastern crows until the end of the quest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thalin's ability fires before the "Surge" keyword can resolve, here's the [official FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/lotr-lcg/support/LotR-FAQ.pdf) entry:

> When an enemy card is revealed from the encounter
>   deck, Thalin’s ability resolves before any keyword or
>   “When Revealed” card effects on the encounter card

Comment: What about when you're not playing with Thalin? Do you just cycle through the Eastern Crows cards until the end of the game? Or do you have to defend against the crows but not attack until the deck empties in order to shuffle the discard pile?

Comment: I guess you could do that, but at that point the game should be easily won by questing anyway.
Also, i found [this thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/644675/infinite-loop-crashed-my-game-eastern-crows-thalin) on BGG that talks about this exact situation.

Comment: The last post in that thread basically says you're stuck if you get to the end of the deck with 2 or 3 crow cards.

Comment: @Shem Why are you stuck?  I can see that you might be drawing crows for the rest of the game, but that doesn't break anything.

Comment: @bwarner That's lame. Gamers would call itta glitch.

Answer (score 2):

Thalin's **revealed** ability triggers before **Surge** so Eastern Crows immediately go back into the encounter deck and no surge card is drawn.

As long as the Eastern Crows aren't used as shadow cards, you'll have a pretty easy time with your quest phases for the rest of the game.